# What is the issue with this factory function?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

In the below code, I write a factory method to create objects of a type in a class heirachy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

enum Type {
    _Base, _A, _B, _C
};

class Base{
private:
    Type type = _Base;
public:
    virtual Type getType(){
        return type;
    }};

class A : public Base{
private:
    Type type = _A;
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

class B : public Base{
private:
    Type type = _B;
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

class C : public Base{
private:
    Type type = _C;
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

shared_ptr<Base> letterFactory(Type which){
    shared_ptr<Base> base = make_unique<Base>(Base());
    switch (which){
        case _A:
            base = make_unique<Base>(A());
        case _B:
            base = make_unique<Base>(A());
        case _C:
            base = make_unique<Base>(C());
    }
    return base;
}


int main(){
    shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfA = letterFactory(_A);
    cout << instanceOfA->getType() << endl;

    shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfB = letterFactory(_B);
    cout << instanceOfB->getType() << endl;

    shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfC = letterFactory(_C);
    cout << instanceOfC->getType() << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

The output is

```
0
0
0
```

How can I make the output

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: There are no virtual data members.

Comment: Override`getType()` instead of redifining `type`

Comment: I thought you couldn't have virtual data members, only virtual functions?

Comment: @CiaranWelsh exactly. And you are doing the opposite.

Comment: `shared_ptr<Base> base = make_unique<Base>(Base());` also seems wrong. Did you mean to use `make_shared`?

Comment: @churill It's not wrong (`unique_ptr` can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr` by design), it's just slightly inefficient (there will be two separate allocations for the object and the `shared_ptr` control block). That and the fact that creating a `Base` instance is entirely unnecessary in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Base` class has a member `type` and a virtual member function `getType()` that returns the value of the member `type`. Your classes `A`, `B`, and `C` derive from `Base`. That means they all have a `Base` subobject. That subobject contains the member `Base::type`. In addition, they all also add another member `type` that is then not ever used by anything. Also, none of them override the `getType` method either. So whenever you call

```cpp
instanceOfX->getType()
```

even if `instanceOfX` points to an instance of one of the derived classes, since none of the derived classes overrite `getType`, you'll end up calling `Base::getType`, which will return the value of `Base::type`, which is always `_Base`…

What you actually wanted was probably something along the lines of:

```cpp
struct Base
{
    virtual Type getType() const = 0;

protected:
    Base() = default;
    Base(Base&&) = default;
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator =(Base&&) = default;
    Base& operator =(const Base&) = default;
    ~Base() = default;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    Type getType() const override { return _A; }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    Type getType() const override { return _B; }
};

class C : public Base
{
public:
    Type getType() const override { return _C; }
};
```

Note that this is almost certainly bad design. The only purpose such a `getType` method could serve is so that client code can find out the concrete type of the object that a `Base*` it got is pointing to. If you ever need this information, your design violates the [Liskov Substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)…

Apart from all that, note that `_Base`, `_A`, `_B`, and `_C` are reserved names [[lex.name]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.name#3) that you're not supposed to use in C++ code…

Answer (score 3):

Your factory is a bit flawed and your `getType()` function is not overridden in the derived classes. I guess you wanted to do something along this lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

enum Type {
    _Base, _A, _B, _C
};

class Base{
public:

    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual Type getType() const {
        return _Base;
    };
};

class A : public Base{
public:
    virtual Type getType() const override {
        return _A;
    };
};

class B : public Base{
public:
    virtual Type getType() const override {
        return _B;
    };
};

class C : public Base{
public:
    virtual Type getType() const override {
        return _C;
    };
};

unique_ptr<Base> letterFactory(Type which){
    switch (which){
        case _Base:
            return make_unique<Base>();
        case _A:
            return make_unique<A>();
        case _B:
            return make_unique<B>();
        case _C:
            return make_unique<C>();
    }

    return nullptr;
}


int main(){
    shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfA = letterFactory(_A);
    cout << instanceOfA->getType() << endl;

    shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfB = letterFactory(_B);
    cout << instanceOfB->getType() << endl;

    shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfC = letterFactory(_C);
    cout << instanceOfC->getType() << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

Notice that we got rid of the `type` member completely and instead properly overrode the `getType()` function. Furthermore, factory functions like this usually return `unique_ptr` (which can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr` if you really want to).

Comment: This works but seems a bit excessive to have to write out getters for subclasses. What if I have 10 variables and 10 subclasses? Would there be a more elegant solution to do the same thing?

Comment: @CiaranWelsh depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. If you have 10 different members that are all shared by each derived class why inheritance in the first place?

Comment: Virtual methods are for when subclasses have different _behavior_ from the base class. If it's just a variable, skip virtual methods, and add a `protected` base constructor. Then have each subclasses' constructor invoke the base constructor and pass any data custom to the base.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh You only need to override the getters if they actually return *different* things. Makes sense, no?  You don’t need to provide different getters though, you can also return a member variable that is appropriately initialised by all derived classes via a call to the parent constructor.

Comment: My actual factory is a poker hand evaluator function. It starts by testing whether the base `Hand::isa()` `RoyalFlush`, if so return it, if not move on an evaluate the `StraightFlush`. Therefore, I'm returning subclasses of the `Hand` type depending on behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code a bit just to apply some of the best practices:

- use `enum class` instead of the raw `enum` because `enum class` represents a scoped enumeration type and it is also strongly typed which means you cannot convert it that easily to integer as the raw `enum` (that's why we have `to_integral` template function)
- prefer not to use `using namespace std;` because it imports the entirety of the std namespace into the current namespace of the program
- also, I think you wanted to use `std::make_shared` instead of `std::make_unique`

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

enum class Type : int {
    _Base = 0,
    _A    = 1,
    _B    = 2,
    _C    = 3
};

class Base{
private:
    Type type = Type::_Base;
public:
    virtual Type getType(){
        return type;
    }
};

class A : public Base{
private:
    Type type = Type::_A;
public:
    virtual Type getType() override {
        return type;
    }
};

class B : public Base{
private:
    Type type = Type::_B;
public:
    virtual Type getType() override {
        return type;
    }
};

class C : public Base{
private:
    Type type = Type::_C;
public:
    virtual Type getType() override {
        return type;
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<Base> letterFactory(Type which){
    switch (which){
        case Type::_A:
            return std::make_shared<A>();
        case Type::_B:
            return std::make_shared<B>();
        case Type::_C:
            return std::make_shared<C>();
        default:
            return std::make_shared<Base>(Base());
    }
}

template <typename Enum>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<Enum>::value,
                                  typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>::type
to_integral(Enum const& value) {
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>(value);
}

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfA = letterFactory(Type::_A);
    std::cout << to_integral(instanceOfA->getType()) << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfB = letterFactory(Type::_B);
    std::cout << to_integral(instanceOfB->getType()) << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr<Base> instanceOfC = letterFactory(Type::_C);
    std::cout << to_integral(instanceOfC->getType()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABWABykADqgWE6rR6hiZmvv6BdDZ2jkYubl6KypiqQQwEzMQEIcam5koqanQZWQQxDs6uHt4Kmdm5YQX15baV8dVeAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzLbIhlgA1OKjOkaYRiQAnnPY4gAMAIJjE1OYs/PqdcSYzEbrW7s7WsbTk8wKCtMAKis%2BhyDTtgSzAOyyHbTEHTAD60iehzmABFpptSNdQeDtsjYdNOIjgaCIWjRnDzEicTo8XDRtdxP8YXMgTdto9ntNIUpKbSfMQ8AA3ZgEDhEkHvT7TAgfaH4t6ikAgCFQmnXHwGJysPDIED86acvDZAxsCVC4CYAiCzAQLqs9XIs4Efq0YWiuXYkGU6k7Z0OukMl6o74KpUqpmywHyjnc3lqx16w4ioXo41SsG7UZsxXK1XqzXa3XG6YGo2i03TVCc1wcmbmiOWw02u2fd1oqkUhtJik7T1M6Y%2BlP%2B5mYcvbdlcnl8iPZ6NiuFx6WyZs7X2p8Oo0EZ61Z0U5w3GgtFkt4MtBiugq3Vsd10Fu11N2nXNskzt%2B5ABln7/shocL5GjtexyXSnTuucqu%2BS5aiurCRuueafFuxbEKW0LPsilbWsQtonjOi5Og2F7Uuh1x1OgUoKAgWSYOgYI%2BAQxBzDoPbrNM7AELyxAAGLMKoqwQNmADuCAqggZoIaCChcYQyAINMEA8XxAm0ohoIsEokbxtsQFyUh1b4VKRjMAA1pgYJESR6DUYm2CmqeckKYck4QqpakgkeKHTJpIDaXpBnEWcxnzNOZlmuh9lWUpv52fZjm2i5bn6YZXnUX%2Box%2BRZiFYFQzAGKwBChWp4XOQQBGubp0WeaR1G0QlEA9qa/myWeWG7HV1y8kYPjCLyRw6GOtAXIc2C0MYVytnQdSYAAHuyNZaN1uX5ZNSr6XgVDUS5eAKGCdyXPMvX9QlUrcoYmBYhh9nHSdyKdVNLkGNorisCstjAGCaE6FtG3YFKaFvSAJ47EQYK/JgwDEGwEAvQ8Q0EFIABsGpsAYmBdACNUOVWTl1DyKpggpEPzOdizTVKV1YMQt33Y99qbX1r3veTZl7XD1WNi6dK/NM2m2OZgkgi5MWkeRlGlbKCU/LQaO0IMADyVCouiDFMax7HECsnE/gmDMRi5aAGH81HUcKqB/fQANA6wEC2KLEtSwAtOsuabl0CM6/M%2BMgJYrDuuq3PFWRFFUT5gvYML5uYJL0hHHCsuuPLRCK8rnzxtIatHRrfTa/Muu/f9gPA2bmRi8HVDSNbCW2/m9vtbrLmu%2B76t5YRXt877NH%2B4HucWySMuGnLbHR0rNk6InyLJ1r5dOxnhtZybOciG3RfYCXUFl47JKV9obu4RGOWbO7l5DD0rAgEM7hDKQphDJsx%2BoAff4yHIzl9AM0KSKMnDH5lZ%2B7z0OkeNwAB0oybJ4TYABOUYQCgHcH%2BP8QB/xIZCAPtwY%2Bp9z6kEvkMY%2BCgQAIjfufHocBYAwEQCgVAzU8DsDIBQCAaASFkJAMABQXUfBEVQAQUgVBSFMQwRAJwB9kFOFsFkFYB8X6kCoYseg4taC3R4cfLA2lRDsGkaQfAZw0jFgwe/CwI1Uha2GMg/6%2B8NHKicEDRWegsBCNfhyIwFieg0HoEwNgHAeD8EEMIUQKA5ByCEHgJwGDIA9FQBRII6jLb4VhBIG%2BMgeDTEtuLUY6CUhpA0BASwjRTCYksBUOICRBB%2BACMUYI%2Bg8i5MiAUrJVQ3CYkKKkAppQGhFLCFUxJtSWjlI6JUxQLQ0mCDRtkNpOTOA9AUPfQYXA94HyPifRRqCRqeEhpbSG3AczIAfBASiV0dIIxBvgaOswn6YmmHoahrg9nPwRtfWQMhX7SPtqQL%2B3B3A/yATA9wnBNiSEhpIL5Dz3BwKGAg0g1jXk/02NwSQng3nAM8P8IBkh3CjFgUgi%2BB90GYNINg3epA8GEJTgqFhFCqE%2BFIdUDJOySCCDsYwFgCjnFcSBj4GxfzJlIpQQfMYnBpgiQIOJWZ8zFnLNWes2gmzrnv1uQgc4RNKDjP%2Bcfax3BPBPPcP8TgngwGbE4JITY/xuCLKmRo1BqKsE3M/iAB5P9IZAM4EAzYkNNibHcF861kheAGPifq5Bhr0Umr%2BZIRB0yUXerFT0GCAQNDcCAA%3D%3D)